# nginx on Debian returns 404 even though requested file exists

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, nginx, webserver

nginx on Debian returns 404 even though requested file exists

I followed the official documentation (https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian) to install nginx on Debian.

> 1. Install the prerequisites:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release debian-archive-keyring
> ```
>
> 2. Import an official nginx signing key so apt could verify the packages authenticity. Fetch >the key:
>
> ```
> curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor \
>   | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
> ```
>
> 3. Verify that the downloaded file contains the proper key:
>
> ```
> gpg --dry-run --quiet --no-keyring --import --import-options import-show /usr/share/keyrings>/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg
> ```
>
> 4. If you would like to use mainline nginx packages, run the following command instead:
>
> ```
> echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
>   http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
>   | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
> ```
>
> 5. Set up repository pinning to prefer our packages over distribution-provided ones:
>
> ```
> echo -e "Package: *\nPin: origin nginx.org\nPin: release o=nginx\nPin-Priority: 900\n" \
>   | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/99nginx
> ```
>
> 6. To install nginx, run the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install nginx
> ```

After finishing the installation I move on to the beginners guide (https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html). I ran `sudo nginx` to switch it on before moving on to step 7.

> 7. First, create the `/data/www` directory and put an `index.html` file with any text content into it and create the `/data/images` directory and place some images in it.

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/data/
mkdir /etc/nginx/data/www
set +H
echo -e "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>My First Website</h1>\n<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n</body>\n</html>" \
    | sudo tee /etc/nginx/data/www/index.html
set -H
mkdir /etc/nginx/data/images
cp /home/alex/Pictures/IMG_0685.jpg /etc/nginx/data/images/sample.jpg
```

> 8. Next, open the configuration file. The default configuration file already includes several examples of the server block, mostly commented out. For now comment out all such blocks and start a new server block:
>
> ```
>   http {
>       server {
>       }
>   }
> ```

So I edited the config file with `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

```
user    nginx;
worker_processes    auto;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log   main;
    sendfile    on;
    #tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    #gzip   on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /data/www;
        }

        location /images/ {
            root /data;
        }
    }
}
```

> 9. Changes made in the configuration file will not be applied until the command to reload >configuration is sent to nginx or it is restarted. To reload configuration, execute:
>
> ```
> sudo nginx -s reload
> ```

I did exactly that. Then I ran curl to check my progress.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:80/index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
curl 127.0.0.1:80/images/sample.jpg

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So the server is installed but I get a default page instead of my own `index.html`. Also the photo returns a 404. I checked the logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/nginx/access.log

127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2023:16:40:55 +0000] "GET /images/sample.png HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0" "-"

sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

2023/07/08 16:40:55 [error] 1212021#1212021: *11 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/images/sample.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /images/sample.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Does my config file lack essential lines? What should I add, edit, or delete to make the server work as expected?

Comment: Do `/data/`, `/data/www` and `/data/images` (not `/etc/nginx/data` nor `/etc/nginx/data/images`) exist? That's what is asked to do in your quoted documentation (part 7.).